# Which JavaScript file is used on page Customer -> Addresses?

Tags: javascript

On the following page:

Customers -> Manage Customers -> Click on a customer -> Addresses

If there are 2 or more addresses, you can click on an address and the address appears in the "Edit Customer's Address" box.

I can tell this is done in JavaScript, but which file contains the code for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a single JS file, but in the template file itself:

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customer/tab/addresses.phtml
```

Have a look at the function `setActiveItem` and the calls of this function.